# When will TRY_PARSE find a valid date wrapped in special characters?

Tags: sql, .net, t-sql

I am attempting to understand how `TRY_PARSE` actually works under the hood. I've read through the [Documentation for TRY_PARSE by Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-parse-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15.). The documentation makes sense until I run some of my own tests. Using `2022-01-26T12:00:00.000Z` and `#2022-01-26T12:00:00.000Z#` I will get a valid DateTime returned from the `TRY_PARSE` function; however, using `!2022-01-26T12:00:00.000Z!` I will get null returned from the `TRY_PARSE` function.

What special characters are allowed to wrap a date? Why does the `#` work but not `!`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `TRY_PARSE` function uses the .NET CLR to parse the values, so the rules for `TRY_PARSE(@s As datetime)` are the same as for .NET's `DateTime.TryParse` method:

> [DateTime.Parse Method (System) | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parse?#parsing-and-style-elements)
> Any leading, inner, or trailing white space character in s is ignored.
> The date and time can be bracketed with a pair of leading and trailing NUMBER SIGN characters ("#", U+0023), and can be trailed with one or more NULL characters (U+0000).

If your string uses any "special" character other than `#` around the date, it will not parse.

Also, if you have a mis-matched `#` at the start or the end of your date, it will not parse.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for. I couldn't use the right question in Google to get to that page of documentation.